# When to use `numpy.append()`?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have been reading in multiple places (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60853501/5218354)) that [`numpy.append()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html#numpy-append) should never be used.

For example, if one wants to stack multiple arrays together, it is much better to do so via an intermediate Python `list`:

```py
import numpy as np


def stacker(arrs):
    result = arrs[0][None, ...]
    for arr in arrs[1:]:
        result = np.append(result, arr[None, ...], 0)
    return result


n = 1000
shape = (100, 100)
x = [np.random.randint(0, n, shape) for _ in range(n)]


%timeit np.array(x)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 17.6 ms per loop

%timeit np.concatenate([arr[None, ...] for arr in x])
# 100 loops, best of 3: 17.7 ms per loop

%timeit np.stack(x)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 18.3 ms per loop

%timeit stacker(x)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 12.5 s per loop
```

I understand that `np.append()` creates a copy of both its NumPy array inputs and this is much more inefficient than `list.append()` or `list.extend()` in this use-case. However, I find it hard to believe that NumPy developers just added a useless function.

**So, what is the use-case for `numpy.append()`?**

Answer (score 1):

Look at its code:

```
arr = asanyarray(arr)
if axis is None:
    if arr.ndim != 1:
        arr = arr.ravel()
    values = ravel(values)
    axis = arr.ndim-1
return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
```

It's just a simple interface to `concatenate`.  With `axis` it's a direct call to `concatenate`.  Without it it `ravels` the inputs, which often causes a problem. And it converts scalars to arrays.

If you have a 1d array, then it is an easy way to add one value:

```
 In [8]: np.append(np.arange(3), 10)                                                            
 Out[8]: array([ 0,  1,  2, 10])
```

but `hstack` is just as nice:

```
 In [10]: np.hstack([np.arange(3), 10])                                                         
 Out[10]: array([ 0,  1,  2, 10])
```

People write functions that seem to be a good idea at the time, usually with a specific use in mind.  But the actual use (and misuses) may be different than anticipated.

`np.stack` is a more recent, and useful addition.

For a while there was a note in the docs urging us to use `concatenate` and `stack` and avoid all the other stack's, but that's been toned down.  Now they just have:

> This function makes most sense for arrays with up to 3 dimensions. For
>   instance, for pixel-data with a height (first axis), width (second axis),
>   and r/g/b channels (third axis). The functions `concatenate`, `stack` and
>   `block` provide more general stacking and concatenation operations.